# Is there an elegant way to make main() in python periodically run again?

Tags: python

I'm making a very basic weather tracker app, and I want it to track live (I want to use it as a kiosk on a raspberry pi in my dorm room). I figure the way to do this would be to use `sleep`, but is there a more elegant way to wrap my main() so that it re-runs every x-period of time?

My code is just structured as follows:

```
def function1():
    # do things

def function2():
    # do things

def function3():
    # do things

def main():
    # code that creates GUI
    function1()
    function2()
    function3()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There's a million ways to do this. You'll have to decide whether you want your process to run continually, or use whatever your operating system's preferred scheduler is to run the process to termination periodically. For example, un Unix-y systems, `cron` is popular.

Comment: You could use cron job as a scheduler to wrap it up. Suppose your python filename is main.py, and you want it to run every 5 minutes. Then you could make it like `*/5 * * * * python main.py`. Read this for the detail https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to invoke this script from a terminal, and you are using a Unix/Linux OS:

```
while true; do python your_script.py; sleep 2; done
```

Replace `your_script.py` with your file name and `2` with the period you want in seconds.

If you want to do within the script, you could put an infinite while loop to call main at periodic intervals:

```
import time

def main():
    print("1")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything. Not sure why, seems logical to me.

Comment: How are you invoking the script?

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
        time.sleep(2)`

Comment: Same exact way you suggested it within the script. Sorry, forgot specifics.

Comment: Are you typing that command in the terminal? Does it show any issues? With the code above, you should simply be able to do: `python your_script.py`.